# Express server with React - This site can’t be reached

Tags: reactjs, express, twilio

I'm trying to run an Express server and React app together. When I use npm run server it starts the react server instead of the express server. If I go to the localhost for the express server ("http://localhost:3001/api/greeting") I get a message saying "This site can’t be reached".

I set up my server with these instructions:  https://www.twilio.com/blog/react-app-with-node-js-server-proxy

It fails when I test the server I've created.

server/index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const pino = require('express-pino-logger')();

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(pino);

app.get('/api/greeting', (req, res) => {
  const name = req.query.name || 'World';
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(JSON.stringify({ greeting: `Hello ${name}!` }));
});

app.listen(3001, () =>
  console.log('Express server is running on localhost:3001')
);
```

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "create-cep-extension-scripts": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-pino-logger": "^4.0.0",
    "node-env-run": "^3.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "pino-colada": "^1.4.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "create-cep-extension-scripts start",
    "build": "create-cep-extension-scripts build",
    "test": "create-cep-extension-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "create-cep-extension-scripts eject",
    "archive": "create-cep-extension-scripts archive",
    "server": "node-env-run server --exec nodemon | pino-colada"
  }
```

npm run server is supposed to start my express server and display a JSON response with a "Hello World!" greeting. Instead I'm getting a page with a message "This site can’t be reached."

Comment: do you at least see `Express server is running on localhost:3001` in your terminal

Comment: No, it's not logging anything

Comment: Under the "This site can't be reached" There is an error:  ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: well of course, if it does not even start the server, you wont be able to connect :P. Make sure you configured everything correctly. you might need some variables in a `.env` file to be used by `node-env-run`.

Comment: The article I was following says to create the .env file but it never said what to put in it.

Comment: ok well then you probably did not need anything. did you run `npm install` or `yarn` to install everything ?

Comment: I used yarn to add everything so far as I can tell

Comment: If I type `node server/index.js` into the terminal it works. As such, it seems my `nodemon` isn't working correctly.

Comment: try running `nodemon server/index.js` instead

Comment: -bash: nodemon: command not found

Comment: i meant try replacing your `server` script with just `nodemon server/indexj.js`, of course of `nodemon` is not installed globally it wont be found :P

Comment: That starts the server for my react app and not my express app for some reason.

Comment: does not make any sense :p your react app runs from the script `start`

Comment: ? Something is already running on port 3000. Probably:
  /usr/local/bin/node /Library/Application Support/Adobe/CEP/extensions/edit-master-panel-react/node_modules/create-cep-extension-scripts/scripts/start.js (pid 1767)
  in /Library/Application

Would you like to run the app on another port instead? (Y/n)

Comment: I don't understand why it's doing that either.

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules` and start over haha by doing `yarn` in your project's directory. Seems strange!

Comment: I'll give that a try

Comment: Hey, I wrote that post. Are you able to clone, install and successfully run the complete starter [project from GitHub](https://github.com/philnash/react-express-starter)?

Comment: @philnash - I already had a react app so I didn't run the complete starter. Instead I followed these instructions: https://www.twilio.com/blog/react-app-with-node-js-server-proxy    I changed the package.json "server" to nodemon server/index.js and it seems to work if I then run yarn run dev from terminal.

Comment: Huh, that's weird that it wouldn't just pick up `server/index.js` without that. Unless you have a file in the root of the project called `server.js` too. Glad it's working for you now though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you ran `npm install` before doing anything? Your package.json file seems to miss one outer curly bracket. I think your `npm run server` command does not run because your project is missing the dependencies like `node-env-run`, `pina-colada` or `nodemon`. Also, you should add an empty `.env` file in the top level of your project.

Comment: That's not my entire package.json - I just wanted to show what was in my devDependencies and scripts. I ran yarn add for all of the dependencies. I have a .env file at the root but it's not empty because of the create-react-app. I've tried emptying it but that didn't seem to help.